# saving pcd map for ccny_rgbd package

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have tried the instructions on the wiki page of ccny_rgb package.

After running the following sequence of commands,

roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true

roslaunch ccny_rgbd vo+mapping.launch

the map can be seen in rviz (sometimes it doesn't work but after restarting all nodes, it works) but after running

rosservice call /save_full_map "mymap.pcd"

it gives the following error:

ERROR: Service [/save_full_map] is not available.

However with rosservice list, a different service "/save_pcd_map" can been seen and after calling this service no error occurs but no map is saved as well.

rosservice call /save_pcd_map "mymap.pcd"

Did someone try this or have some suggestion how to save a map for this package? I tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 using ros fuerte.

Thank you in advance,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59465/saving-pcd-map-for-ccny_rgbd-package/) by [zahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4557/zahid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried it earlier and it works fine on Fuerte. You are right, the name of service has changed [Wiki-help needs to be updated].

Here is how to save the Pcd file:

rosservice call /save_pcd_map /home/your_user_name/my_map.pcd

---

Originally posted by [usman](https://answers.ros.org/users/4430/usman/) with karma: 81 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-05-16**:
Yes, the service name changed, but I haven't updated the wiki yet. The change was due to the fact that there are now 2 formats for the full map: pcd and octomap, hence the /save_pcd_map and /save_octomap services

**Comment by [zahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4557/zahid/) on 2013-05-21**:
true, it works with /save_pcd_map. I have also tried to save the octomap and it works fine as well. Thank you Usman and Ivan